# Firebase "Failed to convert a value of type java.util.HashMap to int"

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

At this line of my code in my `OnDataChange()` method in the `ValueEvenListener`:

```
int latest = dataSnapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
```

I'm getting a `DatabaseException` with the error `Failed to convert a value of type java.util.HashMap to int`.

However, in my database, you can take a look at the image  below:

[image]

It is obviously not a `HashMap` but an `int`. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? What can I do to fix it? Why is it retrieving a `Hashmap` when the value is `int`?

**Full dataSnapshot:**

```
final DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        database.child("Campaigns").child(key).child("count");
        database.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                int latest = dataSnapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
                button.setText(latest + "");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.error) + ": " + databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

**Database:**

```
Campaigns:{
  -JDKKDJIIDJFIDJKDK:{
      count:2432
   }
}
```

Comment: share the declaration of `dataSnapshot` and also what you are adding to it

Comment: @AndroidMechanic sure, ust a sec

Comment: if the dataSnapshot has only the value that u want..in our case 2580 try

int latest =  Integer.parseInt(dataSnapshot);

also, maybe you should convert datasnapshot.toString() but i dont remember EDIT: if this doesnt work please Log the dataSnapshot so i can provide you with full answer

Comment: It didn't work, I get a NumberFormatException. And please explain what do you mean by "Log the dataSnapshot". Thank you for trying to help

Comment: inside the OnDataChange insert this line - > Log.w("eeee", dataSnapshot.toString()); , then look in the logcat after you run the app, and search for something with the name "eeee"

Comment: I'll edit my question

Comment: @Tony dataSnapshot is at least  20 lines of code...

Comment: hi @AbAppletic, your problem is in the **final**, remove it and it should work. Also do this `database = database.child("Campaigns").child(key).child("count");`

Comment: @Wilik no it isn't, see my answer below

Comment: @AbAppletic it's because you're not saving the value to the database variable in this line `database.child("Campaigns").child(key).child("count");` (you should do this `database = database.child("Campaigns").child(key).child("count");`) and remove the **final** because **final** keyword makes the variable value can't be modified.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out I had to child dataSnapshot to my destination again. E.g:

```
int latest = dataSnapshot.child("Campaigns").child(key).child("count").getValue(Integer.class);
```

By default `dataSnapshot` is actually my whole database.

Answer (score 4):

Your `ValueEventListener` is attached to the whole database.

```
// This line gets a reference to the whole database
final DatabaseReference database =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

// This line creates a child DatabaseReference, but you don't assign
// the child to a variable
database.child("Campaigns").child(key).child("count");

// This line adds a ValueEventListener to the whole database
database.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
```

What you want instead is this:

```
final DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
final DatabaseReference countRef = database.child("Campaigns").child(key).child("count")
countRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    // ...
});
```

You can see that in the latter example the ValueEventListener is attached to the child reference, not to the root.

Answer (score 3):

This should work if we assume that the dataSnapshot is right.

```
final DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
database = database.child("Campaigns").child(key).child("count"); // replaced

        database.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                int latest = Integer.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString()); // replaced
                button.setText(latest + "");
            }

            @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.error) + ": " + databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Reminder : **addValueEventListener** will run everytime there is a change in the dataSnapshot.
If you want to run it just once use **addListenerForSingleValueEvent** instead.

Comment: I'll try it. And addValueEventListener is what I want,, thanks

Comment: if this doesn't work that means is something wrong with the dataSnapshot and that you should show it even if its 20 line of codes. Or edit your question and insert an example of how your data structure is.

Comment: Now it gives me a `NumberFormatException` since `dataSnapshot.getValue().toString()` is returning the same as dataSnapshot.toString() , which is a HUGE string (20+ lines)

Comment: edit the line "database.child("Campaigns").child(key).child("count");" to "database = database.child("Campaigns").child(key).child("count");"

Comment: okay glad you came up with a solution, you could post it as an aswer for the other users

Comment: I did, thanks. I need to wait 2 days till I can accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
HashMap<String, String> hashMap = (HashMap<String, String>) dataSnapshot1.getValue();
                System.out.println("hehe " + hashMap);
                String demo = String.valueOf(hashMap.get("sets"));
                String name = String.valueOf(hashMap.get("name"));
```

The COde Above ^^^ Worked fine for me.