# Firebase getValue returns as a HasMap with the key regardless of how I ask for it

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

Some of my data is stored in Firebase as like in the screen shot bellow, under a parent called "votes":

[image]

I am trying to pull the value only (-1) but keep getting the whole HashMap.

The key in this case is represented in my code as a variable called `inititorId` and postVotesSnapshot represents the parent snapshot the holds many children as in the screen shot I've attached.

I've tried:

`postVotesSnapshot.child(initiatorId).value`
or
`postVotesSnapshot.child(initiatorId).getValue(Integer::class.java)`

And both got me the whole HashMap with the key causing a crash because I need the value to be an Int.

I've tried:

```
val valueHash = postVotesSnapshot.child(initiatorId).getValue(HashMap::class.java)
val myValue = valueHash[initiatorId]
```

But that doesn't work wither.

I'm not sure what has gone wrong as the code worked perfectly before with the first option I've mentioned and today it suddenly throws an error at me.

Here's the complete Listener:

```
 val refVotes = if (postType == 0) {
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/questions/$mainPostId/main/votes")
    } else {
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/questions/$mainPostId/answers/$specificPostId/votes")
    }



    refVotes.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

        }

        override fun onDataChange(postVotesSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {

            setVotesCount(specificPostId, mainPostId, votesView, postType)

            if (postVotesSnapshot.hasChild(initiatorId)) {

                val voteValue = postVotesSnapshot.child(initiatorId).getValue(Integer::class.java) //this line is the problematic one

                //I do stuff

            }
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
val ref = firebase.child("posts")
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot?) {
    val id = dataSnapshot.child(initiatorId).getValue(Integer::class.java)
  }
override fun onCancelled(error: FirebaseError?) {
  println(error!!.message)
   }
})
```

Assuming, you have the following database:

```
posts
   VMQPBq6YK3bJ12xIjGeTHsqaJC2 : -1
```

Here the dataSnapshot will be at child `posts`, then you need to attach the `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` and access the child `initiatorId`. Also assuming that initiatorId is equal to `VMQPBq6YK3bJ12xIjGeTHsqaJC2`

Comment: Peter thank you for answering. I apologize for not being clear. all the options I've posted trying are already inside a listener. I know how to access the cildren of a database reference, I am only having trouble getting the value of the child when it is stored in this format

Comment: okay use the following `val ids = dataSnapshot.child(initiatorId).getValue(Integer::class.java)`

Comment: Just tried that again, I get back an error saying `Failed to convert a value of type java.util.HashMap to int`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38845516/firebase-failed-to-convert-a-value-of-type-java-util-hashmap-to-int

Comment: Check if your reference is correct, you need to traverse through all the nodes from top to the node above your `integer` node and then you can retrieve it.

Comment: I know it is correct because if I try to ask for the value is as a HashMap and then print it, it prints `VMQPBq6YK3bJ12xljGeTHnsqaJC2=-1`. I appreciate the link to the other question you attached, I am going through it now but at first look it seems like that guy didn't have the full referance, where for me I have no more keys to add to the path as the last one is the `initiatorId` and I already added it to the path with `child(initiatorId)`. I've updated my question to include the complete listener.

Comment: you cant use `$` in android, also add them in `child()`, example child("questions").child(id)...` Also it should be getValue(Integer::class.java) as there is no Int class in java

Comment: My code is in Kotlin, $ is used to access string variables. Also Int is the equivalent of Integer in Kontlin where Integer isn't used.

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#class-references You are obtaining a java class reference in your code, there is no Int java class

Comment: You're absolutely right, unfortunatly even after changing it to Integer it still claims I am trying to convert a HashMap to Int. The weird thing is that it worked before, no idea what has changed I'll kee playing with it and I'll update if I'll figure it out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191002/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-tsabary).